# NPM generates several errors when installing modules

Tags: node.js, npm

It seems to only happen while installing modules requiring node-gyp. It does this with Mongoose and StrongLoop. For example `npm install -g strongloop` gives:

```
C:\Node.js>npm install -g strongloop
npm WARN deprecated json-file-plus@2.0.0: Before v3.0.0, errors in fs.writeFile
would not be propagated
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing strong-fork-syslog@1.2.3
\


> heapdump@0.3.5 install C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongl
oop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild

|
C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-s
upervisor\node_modules\heapdump>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Nod
e.js\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp
.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
/
-
```

And then just stops. It generates an npm-debug.log file (which is way too long to paste).

What may the issue be? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on windows.

#### Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

Get VC++2010 Express from http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express and install it.

Then open cmd as administrator and install `node-gyp` globally using

`npm install -g node-gyp`

This solved it for me.